# React - How to change the language of DataTable component properties of material ui?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, translate

I'm using a Material ui component called DataTable, the problem is that filter fields are in English and I was wondering if there is any way to change their language to Portuguese

below my component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

export default function DataTable({ rows, columns }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}

DataTable.propTypes = {
  rows: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      conteudo: PropTypes.string,
      disciplina: PropTypes.string,
      curso: PropTypes.string,
      data: PropTypes.string,
    })
  ).isRequired,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  columns: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

[image]

I want to translate "unsort, sort by Desc, Filter, Hide..." to english

Comment: you know if it is possible to take out the unsort and the sorts once we have already the arrow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can localize any text label on `DataGrid` by passing a `localeText` object prop to the `DataGrid` like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const localizedTextsMap = {
  columnMenuUnsort: "não classificado",
  columnMenuSortAsc: "Classificar por ordem crescente",
  columnMenuSortDesc: "Classificar por ordem decrescente",
  columnMenuFilter: "Filtro",
  columnMenuHideColumn: "Ocultar",
  columnMenuShowColumns: "Mostrar colunas"
};

export default function DataTable({ rows, columns }) {
  const [finalClickInfo, setFinalClickInfo] = useState(null);

  const handleOnCellClick = (params) => {
    setFinalClickInfo(params);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        onCellClick={handleOnCellClick}
        localeText={localizedTextsMap}
      />
      {finalClickInfo &&
        `Final clicked id = ${finalClickInfo.id}, 
        Final clicked field = ${finalClickInfo.field}, 
        Final clicked value = ${finalClickInfo.value}`}
      {!finalClickInfo && `Click on a column`}
    </div>
  );
}
```

All the keys that can be localized are listed [here](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/cc09f3788d65f9694a0fbc1381681c701b802e47/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/constants/localeTextConstants.ts).
You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-datagrid-localization?file=src%2FDataTable.js) for a live working example of this usage.

Comment: I don't even know how to thank you, I've been looking for this for centuries, thank you very much for your availability

Comment: thx a lot. do you know how to use this one? 
    footerTotalVisibleRows: (visibleCount, totalCount) =>
    `${visibleCount.toLocaleString()} de ${totalCount.toLocaleString()}`,

Answer (score 5):

For our TypeScript installation with MUI Data Grid version == 5.17.9, little bit diffent path to locale text was needed.

```
import { DataGrid, ptBR } from '@mui/x-data-grid'


<DataGrid
  localeText={ptBR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
/>
```

You can check state of traslations here:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/localization/#supported-locales

Comment: Please, look at the link to avoid defining the translations one by one and just set the language to be used by DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

The localeText that worked for me is this path:

```
localeText={ptBR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
```

@mui/x-data-grid": "5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone if needed. (changing the dataGrid footer as well)

In my .jsx I added :

```
import { DataGrid, **ptBR** } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
<DataGrid localeText={ptBR.props.MuiDataGrid.localeText}
```

the result is :

[image]

supported locales at :
https://material-ui.netlify.app/zh/components/data-grid/localization/